# Basics of REST with php

Tags: php, rest

I'm trying to learn the basics of REST and I found a pretty good tutorial (at least it's helped me understand the basics). [This is the tutorial I've been following](http://phpmaster.com/rest-can-you-do-more-than-spell-it-2/) .

Anyway, in this code snippet the author is showing the basics of how a website may use something like `www.example.com/restaurant/42 instead of /?restaurant_ID=42`.

Can anyone explain why this is used

```
explode("/", $path, 2); 
instead of
explode("/", $path);
```

For this example they would generate the same array, but what if it's a longer path such as `Restaurant/item/3` ? Wouldn't you want to separate everything? As you can see, further down in this block they do use explode without defining a limit. Is the first one simply for the resource? (I guess the controller if it were an MVC)

```
<?php
// assume autoloader available and configured
$path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
$path = trim($path, "/");
@list($resource, $params) = explode("/", $path, 2); //why is limit used here?

$resource = ucfirst(strtolower($resource));
$method = strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);
$params = !empty($params) ? explode("/", $params) : array();  //no limit here?

if (class_exists($resource)) {
 try {
    $resource = new $resource($params);
    $resource->{$method}();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
}
}
else {
header("HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's first splitting the entire path into a *resource* and a *params* variable. `$resource` will contain the first element, `$params` the rest. For instance:

```
restaurant/42      -> restaurant, 42
restaurant/item/3  -> restaurant, item/3
foo/bar/baz/boom   -> foo, bar/baz/boom
```

Then, the `$params` string is further broken down into individual items:

```
restaurant/42      -> restaurant, (42)
restaurant/item/3  -> restaurant, (item, 3)
foo/bar/baz/boom   -> foo, (bar, baz, boom)
```

Essentially it's treating the first part special.

You could get the same effect with this:

```
$params   = explode('/', $path);
$resource = array_shift($params);
```

Comment: +1 Not only for clearly explaining the original code but showing a simpler way of achieving the same.

Comment: I understand what explode is doing(as far as how it separates), I'm just wondering why you want to use a limit instead of separating path entirely (by not specifying a limit)? In this example, do we only need the resource when explode is used with a limit of 2? Either way, couldn't we just call $array[0] to obtain the resource? Thanks

Comment: @user As I said, there *are* easier ways to do it. But the way the author of your code does it is also valid. He just thought about the problem differently and arrived at the solution using a different method. Or maybe he thought that way the idea of what he's trying to do is conveyed better, which makes the code more readable. There's no other reason for it.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to be sure there wasn't anything I was misunderstanding. Thanks a lot.